# Set Client IP address to the azure sql server automatically using vso powershell task

Tags: powershell, azure, firewall, azure-sql-server

**Issue** : When i create the new sql server and DB. My next task is to connect with DB but it breaks due Client IP not added in the firewall of sql server.
I don't want to add it manually.
Is there any way to set it using Powershell? and it should be the exact same IP which i am able to see inside azure sql server Firewalls and virtual networks.

**Workaround**
Currently i added the IP range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 using azure sql task but it is not the right way to do it.

```
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'AllowAzure', '0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule` cmdlet. 
To retrieve the current IP I use ipify.org. Example:

```
$clientIp = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.ipify.org' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content

Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule `
            -ResourceGroupName "myrg" `
            -ServerName "myserver" `
            -FirewallRuleName "myrulename" `
            -StartIpAddress $clientIp `
            -EndIpAddress $clientIp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Error displayed when i execute this : Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule : ResourceGroupNotFound: Resource group '34QAResource' could not be found.
At line:3 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule ` -ResourceGroupName "34QAResource"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.FirewallRule.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlServerFirewallRule

Comment: You have to login to azure first and ensure to that the desired subscription is selected.

Comment: I am logged in already using Connect-AzureRmAccount command. Still it displayed error.

Comment: Try whether you can get the resource group using the get-azurermresourcegroup cmdlet. you are not connected to your subscription or it is not selected.

Comment: oh got it. Now new error: Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule : NotFound: Resource not found for the segment 'firewallRules'.
At line:4 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule ` -ResourceGroupName "34QAResource"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.FirewallRule.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlServerFirewallRule

Comment: I use the 'New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule' instead of 'Set-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule'. Now it is working.

Comment: When run through local powershelll it get and set the correct Client IP. But when i run this through VSO release job then the client IP it is getting is different from Client IP in SQL Firewall. Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: I thought you want to add the ip of the build agent to perform certain tasks. Which IP do you want to add?

Comment: I want the IP displayed when you go to SQL server firewall page. When i run the locally then it is getting exactly the same IP. But problem exist with VSO release job.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Why you want to add your local client ip to a sql server using a vsto task? How do you think this should work if your build gets triggered using e. g. CI....

Comment: Frankly speaking i am new to azure and trying to learn things. Yes you are right adding local IP does not sounds good. Where problem is, i have one VSO task which makes connection to the DB. As my DB server does not have client IP so the task failed. Now i am trying to add client IP before my DB connection task run. I found if i add client IP manually which is displayed at SQL server firewall page then my DB connection task running successfully. Thats why i am trying to add that perticular client IP using another VSO powershell task. Please give your suggestion on this. How to achive this.

Comment: My limitation is :- a.) Initially I do not have Client IP added to the SQL firewall. b.) I cannot add Client IP manually. c.) Client IP should not in range like 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Comment: I don't have any problem if Client IP added from VSO job does not match with Client IP displayed at the SQL server firewall page. The thing is, At the end my DB connection VSO task should run successfully. :)